# unable to use continuous delivery on AWS for a django app(nginx, psql)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops, amazon-ecs

I have tried multiple tutorials in order to run my application which is running simply good with docker, django, nginx, postgres. I have my `docker-compose.yml` file ready, should not it be simple to ship it to the cloud ? I tried Elasticbeanstalk, getting multiple errors that are hard to debug. AWS does not seem to support `docker-compose.yml` and I should use their `Dockerrun.aws.json`, I tried also ECS, but it seems also to be not easy.

Does any one know a complete, thorough tutorial on that? By the way, I am using codeship, and all tests runs well, but deployment is also failing all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If docker, I recommend going directly to ECS. Yes, they don't support docker-compose, but ECS is similar enough. Check out the following Github Project for deploying django on ECS

https://github.com/ethanmcc/django-ecs-deploy

You should also look at the following AWS docker-compose ecs-cli utility:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html

Now that I answer your question, I will like to suggest you consider not releasing with docker, especially your database. IMO, one of the key values of AWS is to use some of their managed systems, so for example, using RDS to manage your Postgres database, instead of worrying about maintaining your own up and running 24/7. Same with static files, the best solution (and super cheap) is to either use S3, or better, use CloudFront.

Advertisement: Check out the following link for an opinionated templated I created that shows my own Infrastructure, used in production by at least two startups. It using docker-compose locally, but I use Elastic Beanstalk (Python) + RDS + CloudFront for production, and shows the single deploy command to do this. It is a little more complicated that usual, as it builds the static files as a stand-alone project (using Gulp) and deploys directly to S3/CloudFront, and then copies the based template to the Django project:

https://github.com/dkarchmer/django-aws-template